# Solving a system of linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Consider the following system of inequalities:

$Ax=b$;
$x\geq 0$;

A is a $m\times n$ (non-square) and sparse matrix in which some part of entries are rational. How this system can be solved without using linear programming?

Comment: please explain what mean by "solved".

Comment: I meant, how can the feasibility of this system  be checked without using linear programming?

Comment: There is no general way, but perhaps you can use one of the "theorems of the alternative" such as Farkas's Lemma, Gale's Theorem, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid linear programming? 

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.faqs.org/faqs/linear-programming-faq/

Q6.4: "I just want to know whether or not a feasible solution *exists*."

A: From the standpoint of computational complexity, finding out if an LP
model has a feasible solution is essentially as hard as actually finding the
optimal LP solution, within a factor of 2 on average, in terms of effort in
the Simplex Method; plug your problem into a normal LP solver with any
objective function you like, such as c=0. For MIP models, it's also
difficult - if there exists no feasible solution, then you must go through
the entire Branch and Bound procedure (or whatever algorithm you use) to
prove this. There are no shortcuts in general, unless you know something
useful about your model's structure (e.g., if you are solving some form of a
transportation problem, you may be able to assure feasibility by checking
that the sources add up to at least as great a number as the sum of the
destinations).